# Can't find background mode in Xcode (for my project)

Tags: xcode, flutter

MacOS 10.15 - Catalina

Flutter project

Xcode 11

I want to enable Background mode but as describe on documentation

[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background#2904072)

But I can't find this setting in Xcode in my project
[image]

After click "+" nothing show:

[image]
After click on Capability "+" nothing show
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Click on "+ Capability option", search for background mode, you will be able to add background mode capability from there.

Comment: @AshishChauhan After "+ Capability option" I can't find Background mode